# React-Native FlatList keyExtractor not working properly

Tags: react-native

Hello so I am learning on React Native so I am practising with a simple Todo like app, I want to implement the deletion method so on each and every added item it has an id which I then tried using the **keyExtractor** to then pass in the key of each added item, but seemingly all the items have the same id cause when I click on them to delete all entries are then deleted.

I do not know if the is an error in my Code Logic can I please get help:

**Code Below App.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, FlatList } from "react-native";
import ListItems from "./Components/ListItems";
import InputField from "./Components/InputField";

export default function App() {
  const [GoalListItem, setMyGoals] = useState([]);

  const addGoal = (goals) => {
    setMyGoals((currentGoals) => [
      ...GoalListItem,
      { id: Math.random().toString(), value: goals },
    ]);
  };

  const removeGoalHandler = (goalID) => {
    setMyGoals((currentGoals) => {
      return currentGoals.filter((goal) => {
        goal.id !== goalID;
      });
    });
  };
  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
      <InputField onAddGoal={addGoal} />
      <FlatList
        data={GoalListItem}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
        renderItem={(itemData) => (
          <ListItems
            id={itemData.item.id}
            removeGoal={removeGoalHandler}
            item={itemData.item.value}
          />
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screen: {
    padding: 50,
  },
});
```

**Code below is the ListItems.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";

const ListItems = ({ item, removeGoal, id }) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={removeGoal.bind(this, id)}>
      <View style={styles.goalText}>
        <Text>{item}</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
```

};

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  goalText: {
    padding: 10,
    backgroundColor: "#ccc",
    borderColor: "black",
    borderWidth: 1,
    marginVertical: 10,
  },
});

export default ListItems;
```

**The GoalListItem is looking like this**

```
GoalListItem = [{id:21, value:'Cook pasta'}, {id:233, value:'Make Coffee'}]
```

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with keyExtractor. It seems like you're passing down a function `removeGoalHandler`, which is called back with `itemData.item.id`.

Comment: What is `itemData.item.id`? Can we see an example of what `GoalListItem` might be?

Comment: yeah. I think what you want to pass is itemData.id and not itemData.item.id